# Calculate the amount of water a tool described by an array can contain

Tags: algorithm

There is a tool for collecting rainwater. The transect chart of the tool is described by an array in the length of n.

For example:
for this array {2,1,1,4,1,1,2,3} the transect chart is:
[image: click here]

I am required to calculate the amount of water the tool can sustain, in time and place complexity of O(n).
.
For the array above it is 7 (the grey area).
[image: click here]

**My thought:**

Since it's a graphical problem, my initial thought was to first calculate the maximum of the array and multiply it by n. This is the starting volume I need to subtract from.

For example in the array above I need to subtract the green area and the heights themselves:
[image: click here]

This is where I'm stuck and need help in order to do so in the required complexity.

**Note:** Maybe I'm overthinking and there are better ways to handle this problem. But as I said, since it's a graphical problem, my first thought was to go for a geometric solution.

Any tips or hints would be appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The water level at position `i` is the smaller of:

- The maximum container height at positions <= i; and
- The maximum container height at positions >= i

Calculate these two maximum values for every position using two passes through the array, and then sum up the differences between the water levels and the container heights.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a python implementation of an algorithm similar to the one described by @MattTimmermans. The code reads like pseudocode, so I don't think extra explanations are needed:

```
def _find_water_capacity(container):
    """returns the max water capacity as calculated from the left bank
       of the given container
    """
    water_levels = [0]
    current_left_bank = 0
    idx = 0

    while idx < len(container) - 1:
        current_left_bank = max(current_left_bank, container[idx])
        current_location_height = container[idx + 1]
        possible_water_level = current_left_bank - current_location_height

        if possible_water_level <= 0:
            water_levels.append(0)
        else:
            water_levels.append(possible_water_level)
        idx += 1

    return water_levels


def find_water_capacity(container):
    """returns the actual water capacity as the sum of the minimum between the
    left and right capacity for each position """
    to_left = _find_water_capacity(container[::-1])[::-1]  #reverse the result from _find_water_capacity of the reversed container.
    to_right = _find_water_capacity(container)
    return sum(min(left, right) for left, right in zip(to_left, to_right))


def test_find_water_capacity():
    container = []
    expected = 0
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    expected = 0
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
    expected = 0
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3]   # <--- the sample provided
    expected = 7
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2]
    expected = 10
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, -10, 12, 11, 10, 9, 9]
    expected = 18
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    container = [2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2]
    expected = 12
    assert find_water_capacity(container) == expected
    assert find_water_capacity(container[::-1]) == expected

    print("***all tests find_water_capacity passed***")


test_find_water_capacity()
```